# VB.net: exe file doens't work properly when called from Process.Start(...)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using VB.net. 
I have problem with this command: Process.Start(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ALL_ORACLEINTERFACEFILE"))

In appsetting of web.config, we found:

The problem is like this: Basically, SMSToOracleInterface.exe does two tasks:

1. Create a files in a local folder
2. Copy the files to a folder on Server.

When I double click the exe file directly, it worked well. However, when I run the web application (the application that contain Process.Start...), it did only the 1st task. 2nd task is not done at all.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I got a hin that it is because security problem. Meaning that when I click exe file, the system will use my window credential, meanwhile when I run from application, the system may not have my window privilege to access the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that when we click .exe file to run, it get my window credentials to access the folder on server. Meanwhile, when we run from web application, it doesn't have credentials to access server.